# Setting up FakeSiteContext for urls

Tags: unit-testing, fakedb

I am currently trying to create a unittest for a override I made, but unittesting it seems a bit more difficult than I expected..

```
public class Extension : Original
{
    public fallback(HttpContext context)
    {
       return new HttpContext();
    }  

    public IEnumerable<SiteDefinition> RunOn => new[]
    {
       "Some", "Dome", "Gone"
    };

    public bool AllowedOnSite(string site)
    {
        bool allowed = RunOn.Any(sd => sd.Name == site);
        return allowed;
    }

    protected override bool Process(HttpContext context)
    {
        var site = Context.Site.Name;
        if (Context.Domain.Name == "sitecore" || !AllowedOnSite(site))
        {
            return fallback(context);
        } 
     ....

    }
```

I seem to have a problem with `AllowedOnSite`, I can unit test it by itself, but not as part og `Process`, which is needed to unit test the rest of the code?

How do i include `AllowedOnSite` as always true, as part of the unittest for `Process`?

Unittest:

```
    [Theory]
    [CustomAutoData("Gonw")]
    public void AllowedOnSite_IncorrectSite_ReturnFalse(string site)
    {
        //arrange
        var processor = new MediaRequestExtensions();

        //act
        processor.AllowedOnSite(site);

        //assert
        Assert.False(processor.AllowedOnSite(site));
    }
```

This works as expected, but I don't know how to make this condition true, when I when to unittest the `Process` Method?

```
[Theory]
[CustomAutoData("http://gonw.com","Gonw")]
public void Process_RequestURLIsIncorrect_Return(string url, string name)
{
    // Arrange
    var fakeSite = new Sitecore.FakeDb.Sites.FakeSiteContext(new Sitecore.Collections.StringDictionary
    {
        { "name", "Some" },
        { "b", "Dome" },
        { "c", "Gone" }
    });
    HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest(string.Empty, url, string.Empty);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
    HttpContext httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);

    var processor = new MediaRequestExtensionsMock
    {
        GetHttpContextFunc = () => httpContext
    };
    using (new Db())
    {
        using (new Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextSwitcher(fakeSite))
        {
            //Sitecore.Context.Site.Name = name;
            // Act
            processor.Process(httpContext);

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(string.Empty, httpContext.Response.Output.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I trigger the right if statement in in this test, but if I want to trigger to next one, I have to not trigger the first one, which I can't seem to do. 
I don't see why I have to set `fakeSite`? it is not being used anyway..

What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to change your code to make it more easily unit testable, and remove the dependence on the `Sitecore.Context` object, and instead pass in the required variables as a parameter to your method.

For example, you could do the following and then unit test the `dostuff()` method:

```js
public bool process (string url)
{ 
  dostuff(Sitecore.Context.Site.Name);
}

public bool dostuff(string site)
{
  if(site == "something")
  {
    someotherprocess();
  }
}
```

Comment: But i still have more code, under this if statement which i won't be able to trigger, since i cannot set it?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, update your original question with more details.

Comment: I need to Sitecore.Context.Site a certain value, such that i use that to unittest other condition listed under this first if statement. 

As you suggest, I could move that out to a seperate function, but that would just result in the same problem, being that I cant set the Sitecore.Context.Site.name..

Comment: `Sitecore.Context.Site.Name` is a readonly property, you cannot set it. Please update your original question of an example of what you are trying to do.